# How to add version annotation in existing spring project

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, microservices

I need to add version in java model file which is having lot of documents in mongodb and I'm not allowed to update version in db.

If I try to add version in model file and while updating the older documents which is not having version attribute raises duplicate key exception since we are using save method. I checked the code inside its using insert method which causing duplicate key and its not updating since isNew variable is true. Please help me to add version annotation to perform update on existing records.do we need to manually handle the version?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I guess you need to define default value for version field for older records.
By default you can assign them to zero and you can use it.

Comment: There is no need to implement complicated things.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it by implementing `Persistable` interface and overriding `isNew()` method like that:

```java
public class OptimisticLockEntity extends Persistable<String> {
    @Version
    private Long version;

    @Override
    public String getId() {
        return get_id();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isNew() {
        return isNull(get_id());
    }
}
```

With this approach when you update existing document which doesn't have `version` field value, Spring initializes the field with 0.

This works because by default if `@Version`-annotated field is present, [Spring uses it to define entity state](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/reference/is-new-state-detection.html). So, when you try to update existing document (i.e. having _id value), Spring looks at `version`, and because it is null, it considers entity as new and tries to insert document, which causes an exception because there is already a document with such _id in database.

By implementing `Persistable` and overriding `isNew()` method, we force Spring to use _id for that instead of `version`. But as far as I can see, it doesn't affect the optimistic locking mechanism itself.